# media_handle_sideload() returned post_id being incremented

Tags: php, posts

Currently I'm trying to take screenshots of websites. That works great by using mshots and media_handle_sideload.

However these screenshots need to be associated with my post. I've made a function called

```
upload_image_from_url($url, $post_id)
```

and passed the $post_id into the function

```
$id = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, $post_id);
```

Now the returned value for $id is incremented by 1 from $post_id, e.g. $post_id is 200 and $id is 201. Is it not supposed to be the same id?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I hate it when I just figure it out after I post the question.

But it seems each post can have a number of attachments. Which means each attachment has an ID associated with it. Which was confusing because it shared the same ID style and type as the post.

The following code is able to get the URL of the associated uploaded image

```
$media = get_attached_media( 'image', $post_id ); 
foreach($media as $image) {
  $url_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID,'full');
  echo $url_img[0];
}
```